# Is there any way to convert from decibles (light intensity) or candelas to an RGB value?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rgb, physics, virtual-reality, lighting

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to simulate a lighting effect shown in the dropbox video link below. It's an HVF-ii machine during a glaucoma test. After the initialization (yellow lights), the test begins, showing white lights around the crosshair of varying intensities. I have the light intensity level given in decibels. I am trying to convert this decibel value to a valid RGB value to display on a VR headset (FOVE VR HEADSET). The size of my stimuli (white dots in video) is .04mm^2. Is there anyway with this information to convert candelas to RGB value or decibels to RGB?

Formula described here converts decibel to apostilb.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107988/visual-fields-testing-decibels-of-sensitivity-meaning

3.14 apostilb = cd/m^2 (candelas per meteres squared)

The area I’m working with is .04m^2.

From the decibel values I can calculate candelas.

How do I convert from candelas to an rgb value?

Link of video of actual machine in action.

I’m trying to simulate this lighting effect in UNITY VR development. How can I convert from decibels (light intensity) to an RGB value.

Here is a video of an HVF-II machine during testing:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m05n216kkqbp23w/vid1-aud.mp4?dl=0

Comment: wouldn't this depend on the brightness of the screen, not the rgb value of the pixels?

Comment: does the formula on this page help? [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance)

Comment: That formula does not help. I think it converts RGB to relative luminance given you have the three rgb values. But if you have luminance it doesn’t convert to separate rgb values.